# Save image in php generated with the javascript guillotine plugin

Tags: javascript, php

I have installed this plugin that help you resize, rotate and drag an image, but I can't find the php code that takes these parameters (size, angle e.t.c.) and crops the selected part of the image.

https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine

I have tried some things, but didn't work...
Can anyone help please?

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work exactly? Share a short version of your code and the problem you are facing. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 6):

I used this code called by jQuery ajax:

```
$t_width = 270; // Maximum thumbnail width
$t_height = 304; // Maximum thumbnail height
$new_name = $IMAGE."_crop.jpg";
$path = "{YOUR FILE PATH}";
$img = $_REQUEST['originalFile'];
$tamanios = getimagesize($path.$img);

$ratio = $_REQUEST['scale'];
$w = $_REQUEST['w'];
$h = $_REQUEST['h'];
$x = $_REQUEST['x'];
$y = $_REQUEST['y'];
$rotacion = $_REQUEST['angle'];

$nimg = imagecreatetruecolor($t_width,$t_height);
/*
 * TODO: Check if PNG or other image type
 */
$im_src = imagecreatefrompng($path.$img);
imagealphablending( $im_src, false );
imagesavealpha( $im_src, true );

$im_src = imagerotate($im_src, $rotacion * -1, 0);
imagecopyresampled($nimg, $im_src, 0, 0, ceil($x/$ratio),     ceil($y/$ratio),     $t_width, $t_height, $t_width/$ratio, $t_height/$ratio);
imagejpeg($nimg,$path.$new_name,90);
echo $new_name."?".time();
```